# Server os for original Raspberry pi B+

Tags: operating-systems, pi-b+

According to the [official Ubuntu website](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) you can run Ubuntu on Raspberry pi 2, however:

> Note that the information on this page currently only applies to the Raspberry Pi 2, not the original Raspberry Pi.

I still have an original Raspberry pi which is running pidora. This os reached EOL and now I want to run a headless up to date webserver/fileserver using something that gets supported for a longer period of time.

Is there a Ubuntu version for the Raspberry pi B+ which can be used for a webserver/fileserver?

Comment: No reason to not use raspbian or arch.

Comment: General advice: if in doubt, you probably should use Raspbian.

Comment: would you recommend raspbian jessie lite?

Comment: For a headless system: absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no such thing as a "server OS" (at least not in our market segment). There are certainly package configurations and types of software that make a machine better suited as a server, but there isn't actually anything different about the core operating system. With this in mind, we really need to consider what we want in a "server OS".

For the purposes one would use a Raspberry Pi for, I think we could sum it up with two main points. In the "real world" there are other points, but they don't really apply to our use case.

1. The server should be easy to maintain
2. There shouldn't be a lot of junk installed. This uses extra disk space, bandwidth, and upgrade time. Things like a desktop and Mathematica aren't really needed, so why have them?

In my opinion, Raspbian covers the first bullet really well. Looking at it from the command line, it's very similar to Ubuntu Server. Both are Debian based after all. From the second point... To put it nicely, the default Raspbian distribution is rather bloated.

@Ghanima mentioned Arch, but for most people, that meets the second point, but widely misses the mark for point one. Some people love it, but a large percentage of people find it rather challenging.

My recommendation is to use [Raspbian Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). Just looking at the image shows a much smaller size, and everything you want to install is just an `apt-get` call away.

Comment: I'd take issue with Raspbian is bloated.  What you actually mean is the raspberrypi.org image which includes Raspbian is bloated with additional software which are not part of Raspbian.

Comment: @joan: I don't think the average user would understand the difference, but is that wording better?

Comment: Yes, that's better.  It's just unfair to the people at Raspbian to get the blame for the actions of third parties.

Comment: @joan: I had assumed it was all maintained by the same people, and hadn't really considered that.

Comment: Rsspbian was put together by a couple of guys to build an ARM hard float build of Debian suitable for the Pi.  Debian didn't support the Pi's specific hardware in hard float.  The early raspberrypi.org Pi software was soft float Debian based (which one of my Pis is still using).